# Global Styling of UILabel

Tags: uilabel, interface-builder, extension-methods

I'm trying to have a global control over the look of my app, that contains a couple of UITableViews with labels.

Since I don't want to go to the IB through all the tableviews and cells and labels, I try to do the following:

```
extension UILabel {
    static let cellSubject:UILabel = {
        var thisLabel = UILabel()
        thisLabel.font =  UIFont(name: "Avenir Black", size: 2.0)
        thisLabel.textColor = UIColor.myGreen
        return thisLabel
    }()

}
```

Then, in

```
cellForRowAt indexPath:
```

I do:

```
cell.subject = UILabel.cellSubject
cell.subject.text = "Whatever"
...
```

What I expect to see, is a label with small green type

What I see, is a label as it is defined in the Interface Builder.

Is that what I want inherently impossible, or is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up just subclassing UILabel, and assigning that subclass in the Interface Builder:

```
import UIKit
let fontName = "Avenir Black"

    class cellSubject: UILabel {

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
            self.commonInit()
        }

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            self.commonInit()
        }
        func commonInit(){
            self.font =  UIFont(name: fontName, size: 17.0)
            self.textColor = UIColor.white

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exension UILabel{
  func makeGlobal(){
    self.font =  UIFont(name: "Avenir Black", size: 2.0)
    self.color = UIColor.myGreen
  }
}

cell.subject.makeGlobal()
```

This will be a better approach. Or you could simply subclass a cell and add your properties there and make your label an instance of that.